# Resizing a BTRFS image without mounting it

Tags: filesystem, btrfs, disk-image

I'm trying to resize an image containing a btrfs filesystem:

```
btrfs filesystem resize 16G disk.img
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: resize works on mounted filesystems and accepts only
directories as argument. Passing file containing a btrfs image
would resize the underlying filesystem instead of the image.
```

So is there any workaround to do this WITHOUT mounting the image to a loop device?